# How to populate a List based on a Table and its rows in Dart?

Tags: html, list, html-table, dart

I want to populate a list of Objects based on a HTML Table. Let's say I have the following class:

```
class Employee
{
  String name;
  String department;
  num salary;

  ...methods
}
```

And in my HTML, I have the following table:

```
<table class="table" id="employeeTable">
   <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Name
     <th>Departament
     <th>Salary  
     <tbody id="employeeTableBody">
   <tr>
     <td> John
     <td> 1
     <td> 1500
   <tr>
     <td> Mary
     <td> 2
     <td> 2500
              ...etc    

</table>
```

So, how do I query the table, get its rows, then get its cells to fill my List of Employees (in this case)?

I tried to use something like:

```
    TableElement table = query("#employeesTable");
    Element tableBody = query("#employeesTableBody");
```

But I couldn't find a proper method in TableElement or Element to return TableRowElement, or maybe the cells of it. I tried to get the children nodes also, but without sucess.

A pseudo-algorithm to fulfil this task would be something like this:

```
1. Get the table
2. For each row of the table
2.a Create a new Employee object based on the value of each cell of the row.
2.b Append this object to the Employee List.
3. End
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Scratchweb</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="scratchweb.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="employeeTable">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Departament</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2500</td>
      </tr>    
    </table>

    <script type="application/dart" src="web/scratchweb.dart"></script>
    <script src="https://dart.googlecode.com/svn/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/client/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the Dart:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:math';

class Employee {
  String name;
  String department;
  num salary;

  Employee({this.name, this.department, this.salary});
  String toString() => '<employee name="$name" department="$department" salary="$salary">';
}

void main() {
  var employees = new List<Employee>();
  var table = query("table#employeeTable");
  for (TableRowElement row in table.rows) {
    if (row.cells.length != 3) {
      print("Malformed row: $row");
      continue;
    }
    if ((row.cells[0] as TableCellElement).tagName == "TH") {
      print("Skipping header");
      continue;
    }
    var cells = row.cells;
    var employee = new Employee(
        name: cells[0].text,
        department: cells[1].text,
        salary: parseDouble(cells[2].text));
    employees.add(employee);
  }
  print(employees);
}
```

If you approve of this answer, please remember to accept it. My boss feeds me a slice of bacon every time I successfully answer a question ;)

Comment: That worked like a charm. You should receive a whole piece of Bacon.
I also edited your post, changing the _var_ declaration to the object declararion. I think it makes code more clear to read and understand. If you don't agree, just turn back the edition :P

Comment: And it also helped me to find this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=6417&thanks=6417&ts=1351645784) .

Comment: Nice, but do we need to do "as TableCellElement" in there?

Comment: Yes, otherwise you get a mild warning.