# Add table rows in Dart?

Tags: dart

So I decided to start with Dart and I'm already wondering what's the best way to add new table rows with data.

I tried fetching `tbody` and using its `children.add()` with HTML but it has problems like what if `tbody` doesn't exist.

Comment: This question may help you either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142889/how-to-populate-a-list-based-on-a-table-and-its-rows-in-dart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When adding new table rows in JavaScript, you end up in issues like what if there is no `tbody` or how to determine the last row, but in Dart I think it's easier.

Here's an example:

[image]

```dart
import 'dart:html';

main() {
  // Find the table.
  TableElement table = query('#foo');

  // Insert a row at index 0, and assign that row to a variable.
  TableRowElement row = table.insertRow(0);

  // Insert a cell at index 0, and assign that cell to a variable.
  TableCellElement cell = row.insertCell(0);
  cell.text = 'hey!';

  // Insert more cells with Message Cascading approach and style them.
  row.insertCell(1)
    ..text = 'foo'
    ..style.background = 'red';

  row.insertCell(2)
    ..text = 'bar'
    ..style.background = 'green';
}
```

And if you want to insert a row to the end, simply write:

```dart
table.insertRow(-1);
```

The same thing is true for cells.

Comment: To insert a row to the end, you can also use `table.insertRow(-1)`.